# Giving data to a class property according to another classes property which I get from the database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting data from two tables from database.

Table 1 - Members :

```
        public List<Member> ListMembers()
        {
            List<Member> Members = new List<Member>();

            string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY Id";

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT, sqlConnection))
                {
                    var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        var member = new Member
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                            Name = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(),
                            Surname = sqlReader["Surname"].ToString(),
                            EntryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EntryDate"])
                        };

                        if (member.EntryDate < DateTime.Today)
                        {
                            member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            member.Status = Status.Paid.ToString();
                        }

                        Members.Add(member);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Members;
        }
```

Table 2 - Payments :

```
        public List<Payment> ListPayments(Payment entity)
        {
            List<Payment> Payments = new List<Payment>();

            string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Id = @Id";

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entity.Id;

                    var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        var payment = new Payment
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                            Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["Amount"]),
                            StartDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]),
                            EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"])
                        };

                        Payments.Add(payment);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Payments;
        }
```

The Payment's ID is equal to a specific Member's ID. (If a members ID is 100, all his/her payments will have the same ID 100).

Now... in the **ListMembers()** I gave Statuses "paid" and "unpaid" according to their EntryDate, but I want to give them Statuses according to their LAST Payment. So, instead of:

```
if (member.EntryDate < DateTime.Today)
{
     member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
}
```

it should be :

```
if (lastPayment < DateTime.Today) // lastPayment is just a word I'm using, It's not declared anywhere, I don't know how to get that value.
{
     member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
}
```

I'm really lost here, can someone help me ? I don't know what to do.

Comment: Would the "lastPayment" be the one with the most recent `EndDay`?

Comment: @ColmPrunty Yes. So actually it would be "if(theLastEndDay < DateTime.Today)"

Answer (score 0):

Get member payments:

```
public List<Payment> GetMemberPaymnets(int memberId)
    {
        List<Payment> Payments = new List<Payment>();

        string SELECT = "SELECT ID,AMOUNT,STARTDAY,ENDDAY FROM Payments WHERE Id = @Id order by endday desc";

        using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entity.Id;

                var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    var payment = new Payment
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["Amount"]),
                        StartDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]),
                        EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"])
                    };

                    Payments.Add(payment);
                }
            }
        }

        return Payments;
    }
```

instead of

```
if (member.EntryDate < DateTime.Today)
{
     member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
}
```

you can use something like this

```
 foreach(Member memeber in memeberList)
 {
        List<Payment> memberPayments=GetMemberPayments(member.Id);
        //also you need to check that memberPayments.Count>0
        if(memberPayments[0].EndDay<DateTime.Today)
        {
           member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
        }
 }
```

But if you not need make some operations with member payments you can make  database method that will return memeber payment status status by member id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the latest payment date with the `Member` query. Instead of

```
string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY Id";
```

Try

```
string SELECT = "SELECT m.Id, m.Name, 
m.Surname, m.EntryDate, MAX(p.EndDay) AS EndDay FROM Members m
JOIN Payments p ON p.Id = m.Id
ORDER BY m.Id";
```

and then replace this:

```
if (member.EntryDate < DateTime.Today)
{
     member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
}
```

with this:

```
var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"])
if (endDate < DateTime.Today)
{
    member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
}
```

This assumes that there will always be one payment for a member. If there might be a member with no payments, you'll have to do some null checking and a left join.